ERROR The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"SettingsScreen"} was not handled by any navigator
I just started to learn and create a mobile app with react. But I am stuck on navigation tabs and I can't find a solution to it, for now.
My app have a bottom bar with 3 buttons on it. When I tried to navigate from home to SettingsScreen I have the error from the Subject.
My code is:
TabNavigator.tsx
// TabNavigator.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
import HomeScreen from '../app/Screens/HomeScreen';
import SettingsScreen from '../app/Screens/SettingsScreen';
import LogOutScreen from '../app/Screens/LogoutScreen';

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

const TabNavigator: React.FC = () => (
  <Tab.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: 'black' },
      tabBarLabelStyle: { color: 'white' },
    }}
  >
    <Tab.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Tab.Screen name="SettingsScreen" component={SettingsScreen} />
    <Tab.Screen name="LogOutScreen" component={LogOutScreen} />
  </Tab.Navigator>
);

export default TabNavigator;


App.tsx
// App.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import AppBar from './AppBar';
import TabNavigator from './components/TabNavigator';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <TabNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;


AppBar.tsx
// AppBar.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { StackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { RootStackParamList } from './assets/types';
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons';

type NavigationProp = StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList>;

const AppBar: React.FC = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation<NavigationProp>();
  return (
    <View style={styles.appBar}>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
          <FontAwesome name="home" size={20} color="white" />
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Home</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SettingsScreen')}>
          <FontAwesome name="cog" size={20} color="white" />
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Settings</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
          <FontAwesome name="sign-out" size={20} color="white" />
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Logout</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  appBar: {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    padding: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between', // Modifică acest stil pentru aliniere
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    flex: 1,
  },
  button: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginHorizontal: 10,
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 16,
    marginLeft: 5,
  },
});

export default AppBar;


SettingsScreen.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import AppBar from '../../AppBar'; 

const SettingsScreen: React.FC<any> = ({ route }) => {
  return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.content}>
        <Text style={styles.welcomeText}>This is the Settings Screen</Text>
      </View>
    <AppBar/>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  content: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  welcomeText: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});

export default SettingsScreen;


A screenshot with the app is

Screenshot with error


Can you share a snack of your code or your repo link ?
have you tried navigation.jumpTo('SettingsScreen')

@MuhammadFarhan I don't a have a link with the entire project. In my project i have only those files above + HomeScreen and LogoutScreen which has the same problem. It is very weird because from what I read on google, this can be a problem between TabNavigator and App.tsx. But I can't understand what. Where did you say to put that navigation.jumpTo(SettingScreen())

I think the issue might be with tab navigation, try replacing your navigation.navigate("SettingScreen") with navigation.jumpTo('SettingsScreen').
Solution 2:
Further for temporary, remove the appBar and try to navigate between screens on any button click, means create a button in home screen and on that button onPress do navigation.navigate("SettingScreen")

Thank you for helping me. But I have the same error for test number 1 and for the second one, if I try to use jumpTo I have this error in interface  ERROR  TypeError: navigation.jumpTo is not a function (it is undefined), js engine: hermes

The last option i can do is to run your code, for that I would need your complete code, if possible create repo and push your code so that I can check and run at my PC.

@MuhammadFarhan I put the link with code here. Maybe another pair of eyes can help. Thanks in advance. https://github.com/alexandruMMM/MedicalArchivePub

I  changed a bit the code because I have  a lot of tries there, but let me know if you can get the code and check it.

Change SettingsScreen as follows
type NavigationProp = StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList>;

export const SettingsScreen: FunctionComponent<
  NavigationProp<"SettingsScreen">
> = () => {

 ...

}

Something like this should work. The issue is that even though you say which component it is, your navigation props are not defined at the component itself.

Still Not Working. I adjust the code but I have the same error message.

And if you change NavigationPropto StackNavigationProp?

Same thing. Thanks a lot for trying to help me

This is just updating the typing. The error is from js, not from typescript.

You can’t call useNavigation from tab bar buttons.

Note that you cannot use the useNavigation hook inside the tabBar since useNavigation is only available inside screens. You get a navigation prop for your tabBar which you can use instead.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/

Thanks for your answer. But I tried to adapt the code. I created a prop in AppBar.tsx file like
interface AppBarProps {
navigation: any;
}
And use this navigate props further in the code in my SeetingsScreen.tsx. But I receive this error right now
ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined, js engine: hermes

You also need to give your tab bar component to the tab navigator. It looks like you have it outside of that and in each screen. That’s wrong.
